# Help solving a floor equation

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have given the following equation, with the additional info that $x$ and $c$ are positive integers and $p$ is a decimal with $0 \le p \le 1$. My goal is to solve for x:

$x = \lfloor xp + c\rfloor$

I've tried the following, however am not quite sure if my last step is correct and am therefore looking for someone to check my solution/provide me with an alternate, correct solution:

x - floor(x*p) = c

$\lceil x - xp\rceil = c$

$x - xp \ge c$

$x(1-p) \ge c$

$x \ge c/(1-p)$

$x = \lceil(c/(1-p))$

Comment: If $\lceil x-xp\rceil = c$, shouldn't it be $x-xp\le c$? Though also $x-xp > c-1$.

Comment: If $x$ exists then $x$ is a positive integer such that : 

$$\frac{c-1}{1-p} < x \leq \frac{c}{1-p}$$

Comment: I've done a little formatting, Elliot; please see what I've done, and do the rest. Also, you never state what the question is. Presumably, you want to solve for $x$, but you should state this explicitly in the body of your question.

Comment: Please use mathjax formatting.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've fixed the formatting and explicitly stated in the question that I want to solve for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind above.

$x \le xp + c < x+1$

$x(1-p) \le c < x(1-p) + 1$

$x \le \frac c{1-p} < x+\frac 1{1-p}$

Unfortunately as $\frac 1{1-p} > 1$ we've found an upper bound of $x$ but no lower bound.

However we can always "shift" and inequality

$x(1-p) \le c < x(1-p)+1\implies$
$x(1-p)-1\le c- 1 < x(1-p) \implies$
$x(1-p)-1\le c- 1 < x(1-p)\le c < x(1-p)+1 \implies$
$c-1 < x(1-p) \le c$ so
$\frac {c-1}{1-p} < x \le \frac c{1-p}$
$\frac c{1-p} -\frac 1{1-p} < x \le \frac c{1-p}$

Any $x$ in that range will do and there may be multiple values of $x$.

For example if $\frac 1{1-p} \ge 3$ then $\frac 13 \ge 1-p$ and $p\ge \frac 23$. So if we let $p=\frac 23$ and if we let $c$ be, say, $7$ we have

$\frac 7{\frac 13}-\frac 1{\frac 13}= 18< x \le 21$ so we can have $x=19,20, 21$.

Check:

$\lfloor xp +c \rfloor = \lfloor \frac 23x +7\rfloor$.  If $x = 19,20, 21$ then $\frac 23x= 12\frac 23, 13\frac 13, 14$ and $\frac 23x +7 = 19\frac 23, 20\frac 13,21$ and  $\lfloor \frac 23x +7\rfloor=19,20,21 = x$.

Comment: Same formula as that given by user @Abdoul Haki in the comments.